# How to determine what ID has been clicked to display relevant information? PHP / SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I currently have this code which displays all required information on the page:

```
$sql = "select * from livecalls ORDER BY Completion_Date ";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
echo "<tr><td>$row[ID]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[Type]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[VNC_Number]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[Completion_Date]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[Logged_By]</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

This works fine, however I am wanting to be able to click the `$row[ID]` section to open a new window and display the `$row[Problem]` which is related to that **ID** number..

I'm struggling to think how to get the **ID** information across to a new page to be able to search for the right Problem information to display and the code to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a anchor tag for this purpose like

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='yourpage.php?id=".$row[ID]."'>".$row[ID]."</a></td>";
```

and in new page, you can use

`$_GET['id']` for getting the id.

Also while echoing html along with php variable try to do like this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
echo "<tr><td><a href='yourpage.php'>".$row['ID']."</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Type']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['VNC_Number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Completion_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Logged_By']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your not using any php framework (ex. codeigniter). Because if you do,this is easy using routing.

The very basic solution is Passing variables in a URL

http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Then if you want it to open in a new window instead of current window use

Use _blank in your a href

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "select * from livecalls ORDER BY Completion_Date ";
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
     {
       echo "<tr><td><a href='your_url/?id=".$row[ID]."'>$row[ID]</a>`enter code here`</td>";
       echo "<td>$row[Type]</td>";
               ..
               ...
               ....
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer.